# How to count lines in a text file with specified values?

Tags: python

I'm working with a .csv file that lists Timestamps in one column and Wind Speeds in the second column. I need to read through this .csv file and calculate the percent of time where wind speed was above 2m/s. Here's what I have so far.

```
txtFile = r"C:\Data.csv"
line = o_txtFile.readline()[:-1]
while line:
    line = oTextfile.readline()
for line in txtFile:
    line = line.split(",")[:-1]
```

How do I get a count of the lines where the 2nd element in the line is greater than 2?

[CSV File Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jo4w.jpg)

Comment: Could you please share a sample of your csv?

Comment: `with open(txtFile,"r") as o_txtFile:` is missing.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have to update slightly your CSV, depending on the chosen option (for option 1 and option 2, you will definitely want to remove all header rows, whereas for option 3, you will keep only the middle one, i.e. the one that starts with `TIMESTAMP`).

You actually have three options:

**Option 1: Vanilla Python**

```py
count = 0

with open('data.csv', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        value = int(line.split(',')[1])
        if value > 100:
            count += 1

 # Now you have the value in ``count`` variable
```

**Option 2: CSV module**

Here I use the [Python's CSV module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) (you could as well use the `DictReader`, but I'll let you do the search yourself).

```py
import csv

count = 0

with open('data.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.read(file, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        if int(row[1]) > 100:
            count += 1

 # Now you have the value in ``count`` variable
```

**Option 3: Pandas**

[Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) is a really cool, awesome library used by a lot of people to do data analysis. Doing what you want to do would look like:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# Here you are
count = len(df[df['WindSpd_ms'] > 100])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read in the file line by line, if something in it, split it. 
You count the lines read and how many are above 10m/s - then calculate the percentage:

```
# create data file for processing with random data
import random
random.seed(42)

with open("data.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("header\n") 
    f.write("header\n") 
    f.write("header\n") 
    f.write("header\n") 
    for sp in random.choices(range(10),k=200):
        f.write(f"some date,{sp+3.5}, data,data,data\n")


# open/read/calculate percentage of data that has  10m/s speeds
days = 0
speedGreater10 = 0
with open("data.txt","r") as f:
    for _ in range(4):
        next(f) # ignore first 4 rows containing headers

    for line in f:
        if line: # not empty
            _ , speed, *p = line.split(",") 
            # _ and *p are ignored (they take 'some date' + [data,data,data])
            days += 1
            if float(speed) > 10:
                speedGreater10 += 1

print(f"{days} datapoints, of wich {speedGreater10} "+
      f"got more then 10m/s: {speedGreater10/days}%")
```

Output:

```
200 datapoints, of wich 55 got more then 10m/s: 0.275%
```

Datafile:

```
header
header
header
header
some date,9.5, data,data,data
some date,3.5, data,data,data
some date,5.5, data,data,data
some date,5.5, data,data,data
some date,10.5, data,data,data
[... some more ...]
some date,8.5, data,data,data 
some date,3.5, data,data,data
some date,12.5, data,data,data
some date,11.5, data,data,data
```